# C Programming printf from an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

[Screenshot of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L97P.png)

In this program, the user inputs the date and month of the year in terms of numbers.
The output has to be in letters. 
I can't change the variables.

1. I don't know how to print the months in the array. I've tried %s,
   thinking it was a string but it doesn't work.
2. List itemI don't understand why we have to use a pointer if monthnames is already an array? I thought they were the same thing, or equivalent?
   Thanks in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of code. Post the code as text in the question (so that others can easily copy it and to avoid problems with external site dependency).

Comment: Also some of us access the site via mobile devices

Comment: Change the `printf` to be `%s` with `monthnames[month-1]`.

Comment: `scanf("%d/%d", &day, &month)`, `printf("....%d...%s...", day, monthnames[month-1]);`

Answer (score 4):

For printing month name just use

```
printf("%s", monthnames[month]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%c", *monthnames[month]);
```

The latter just prints first character in some month.

`monthnames` is an array of pointers to `char`. So you can use each element in that array to point to a C string - as it is the case in your code.

Note: beware of indexes, in code comments you suggest April is 4-th month. Then December will be 12-th, but your array can have only maximum index 11.

Comment: May need to be `month-1`. Because comments in the code suggest month input starts from `1`. Suggest clarifying with OP or just pointing that out.

Comment: @kaylum: Ok did so. Hope OP can resolve it further on his/her own.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to make some checks of user input before using `month` to index the array. If a user enters a big month like month nr 20 or a negative month like month -5 you will otherwise get a segfault.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist: Feel free to add that suggestion in your answer

Comment: @Giorgi: Thanks, I edited my answer to add the comment there.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable monthnames is an array of pointers to null-terminated strings.
This means that `monthnames[month]` is a pointer to a null-terminated string which you can printf with %s and `*monthnames[month]` is the first char in that string which you can print with %c. `*pointer` means the variable that `pointer` is pointing to.

It might also be a good idea to check user input before using `month` to index the array. If a user enters a big month like 20 or a negative month your program will probably segfault without such a check.

Answer (score 1):

Get a string from an array like that using `monthnames[month]`.

You see, monthnames is an array (but we are denoting it like a pointer) of arrays of `char`s. Since we are treating the pointer like an array here, we don't need to dereference it.

You also probably want to declare your things as `const` if you are not planning to change them. It's not required, but it's good practice.

I made a program to test this in case you don't believe me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* monthnames[2] = { "Jan", "Feb" };

    printf("%s\n", monthnames[0]);
    printf("%s\n", monthnames[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Jan
Feb
```